# How to create entity column with TIME type in TypeORM

Tags: mysql, typescript, typeorm

How do i create an entity column to store [TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) data type from MySQL?

db schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
elapsed_time TIME
);
```

entity:

```
@Entity()
export class TestEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({name: 'elapsed_time'})
    elapsedTime: Date;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

turns out as easy as this

```
    @Column('time', {name: 'elapsed_time'})
    elapsedTime: Date;
```