# How to validate date and time in typeorm and nestjs

Tags: typescript, validation, nestjs, typeorm

I'd like to add validation rule in `typeorm` and `nest.js` based application.

my `entity` and `dto` is following.

My desired validation is following

```
column     data_type  validation_rule

date         DATE       YYYY:HH:MM

begin_time   TIME       HH:MM
```

I'd like to know how to add`TIME` type and how to validate `YYY:HH:MM`

Are there any way to achive this validation rule in `typeorm` ?

My current work is following

If someone has opinion, please let me know, thanks

`event.entity.ts`

```
  @Entity('events')
  export class Event extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment', { type: 'int' })
    id: number;
  
    @Column('date')
    date: Date;

    @Column('date',{name: 'begin_time'})
    beginTime: Date;
}
```

`event.dto.ts`

```
  export class eventRequest {
    @IsInt()  
    id: number;
      
    @IsDateString()
    date: Date;

    @IsDateString()
    beginTime: Date;
}
```

Here is details of entire present tables.

```
mysql> desc events
    -> ;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default              | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                 | auto_increment |
| user_id      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| title        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| date         | date         | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| is_last_date | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| begin_time   | date         | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| end_time     | date         | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| place        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| label_cd     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| detail       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| createdAt    | datetime(6)  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) |                |
| updatedAt    | datetime(6)  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) |                |
| deletedAt    | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Check out this answer regarding time field: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61969436/587594

Comment: Regarding DTO validation, I think you can use  `@IsMilitaryTime()`; or implement your own custom validator. For all this, check out the `class-validator` library: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator