# type of time in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mariadb, nestjs

this is error

```
[7:23:25 PM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

src/users.entity.ts:16:8 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'time'.

16   time:time;
          ~~~~

src/users.entity.ts:16:8 - error TS4031: Public property 'time' of exported class has or is using private name 'time'.

16   time:time;
          ~~~~

[7:23:35 PM] Found 2 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

this is code

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class virtual_user {

 @Column()
  domain_name: string;

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  email: string;

 @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column()
  time:time;

 @Column()
  department: string;
 @Column({ default:1 })
  status_id:number;
}
```

- *how can i fix the error and Thanks .*
- *how can i fix the error and Thanks .*
- *how can i fix the error and Thanks .*
- *how can i fix the error and Thanks .*

Comment: use type `Date` or `string` instead of `time`.

Comment: But I need to use the time
Here are all the types that I can use
# Column types for mysql / mariadb
===================================
https://typeorm.io/entities#special-columns
===================================

Comment: It seems like you're confusing the data type of the column in the database and the type of the field that TypeORM will convert it into once it's loaded out of the database and into an instance of this class in your application. JavaScript and TypeScript have no built in `time`, try `Date`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61968541/how-to-create-entity-column-with-time-type-in-typeorm

Answer (score 0):

there's no type `time` on TypeScript. Instead, use the type `string` or `Date`, and `@Column({ type: 'time' })` or whatever.

Don't confuse typescript types with database datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

```
// For a date with the timezone offset
@Column({ type: 'timestamptz' })
time: Date;
```

```
// For a date without the timezone offset
@Column({ type: 'timestamp' })
time: Date;
```